# How to determine if a bash variable is empty?

Tags: bash, scripting, variables

What is the best way to determine if a variable in bash is empty ("")?

I have heard that it is recommended that I do `if [ "x$variable" = "x" ]`

Is that the **correct** way?  (there must be something more straightforward)

Comment: See: [Test for non-zero length string in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49825114/6862601) on StackOverflow.

Comment: In Bash, `[[ -v VAR]]` is to check if `VAR` is defined, `[[ -z $VAR ]]` is to check if `"$VAR"` is expanded to null string (`""`). Thus, you can use `[[ -v VAR && -z $VAR ]]`. read more [here](https://transang.me/empty-and-unset-variables-in-bash/) (with official reference)

Answer (score 1345, accepted):

This will return true if a variable is unset or set to the empty string ("").

```
if [ -z "${VAR}" ];
```

Comment: That is true - I was going to recommend `-s`, but `test -s ''` exits with a 1, whereas `test -z ''` gives us the anticipated 0.

Comment: what's the inverse of `-z`? if not empty string.

Comment: `if [ ! -z "$VAR" ];`

Comment: the inverse of `-z` is `-n` `if [ -n "$VAR" ];`

Comment: The double quotes ensure that the variable doesn't get split. A simple `$var` on a command line will be split by its whitespace into a list of parameters, while `"$var"` will always be only one parameter. Quoting variables often is a good practice and stops you from tripping up on filenames containing whitespace (among other things). Example: after doing `a="x --help"`, try `cat $a` - it will give you the help page for `cat`. Then try `cat "$a"` - it will (usually) say `cat: x --help: No such file or directory`. In short, quote early and quote often and you will almost never regret it.

Comment: I feel like your answer requires a caveat - namely if your bash script has something like `set -u` then the answer will break/fail at that point.  There is a subtle (and usually ignored) difference between `unset` and `empty`.  Note that the distinction is only really important if it's important to you, or if the script has already `set -u`.

Comment: in `if [ -n "$VAR" ];`, quotes ensure returning 0 for zero-lenght strings.

Comment: In Bash, `[[ -v VAR]]` can be used to check if `VAR` is defined, `[[ -z $VAR ]]` is to check if `"$VAR"` is expanded to null string (`""`). Thus, `[[ -v VAR && -z $VAR ]]` should be the correct answer. read more [here](https://transang.me/empty-and-unset-variables-in-bash/) (with official reference)

Comment: More info on `-n` as the inverse of `-z` from `man test`: `-n string     True if the length of string is nonzero.`

Answer (score 328):

In Bash, when you're not concerned with portability to shells that don't support it, you should always use the double-bracket syntax:

Any of the following:

```
if [[ -z $variable ]]
if [[ -z "$variable" ]]
if [[ ! $variable ]]
if [[ ! "$variable" ]]
```

In Bash, using double square brackets, the quotes aren't necessary. You can simplify the test for a variable that *does* contain a value to:

```
if [[ $variable ]]
```

This syntax is compatible with ksh (at least ksh93, anyway). It does not work in pure POSIX or older Bourne shells such as sh or dash.

See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3870055/26428) and [BashFAQ/031](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031) for more information about the differences between double and single square brackets.

You can test to see if a variable is specifically unset (as distinct from an empty string):

```
if [[ -z ${variable+x} ]]
```

where the "x" is arbitrary.

If you want to know whether a variable is null but not unset:

```
if [[ -z $variable && ${variable+x} ]]
```

Comment: That `if [[ $variable ]]` worked fine for me, and didn't even need the `set -u` that was required by one of the other proposed solutions.

Comment: I think this is better than the accepted answer.

Comment: Why are you recommending a non-portable feature when doing so gives no benefit?

Comment: @AlastairIrvine: I mention portability in the first sentence of my answer, the question title and body contain the word "Bash" and the question is tagged [tag:bash], and the double bracket structure provides [clear advantages](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3870055/26428) in many ways. And I don't recommend mixing bracket styles for reasons of consistency and maintainability. If you need maximum, lowest common denominator portability, use `sh` instead of Bash. If you need the increased capabilities that it provides, use Bash and use it fully.

Comment: You should add `if ! [[ $variable ]]` and `if ! [[ "$variable" ]]` to be complete.

Comment: I edited the answer to make it clear that using `[[` instead of `[` eliminates the need for `"` inside but doesn't eliminate the need for `;` at the end.

Comment: @BrunoBronosky: I reverted the edit. There's no requirement for `;` at the end. The `then` can be on the next line without a semicolon at all.

Comment: You **can** do that, but a puppy dies every time you put `then` on its own line.

Comment: set -u # the only one working with set -u
if [[ ${variable+x} && -n $var ]] ; then
 echo " defined and not null
fi

Answer (score 322):

A variable in bash (and any POSIX-compatible shell) can be in one of three states:

- unset
- set to the empty string
- set to a non-empty string

Most of the time you only need to know if a variable is set to a non-empty string, but occasionally it's important to distinguish between unset and set to the empty string.

The following are examples of how you can test the various possibilities, and it works in bash or any POSIX-compatible shell:

```
if [ -z "${VAR}" ]; then
    echo "VAR is unset or set to the empty string"
fi
if [ -z "${VAR+set}" ]; then
    echo "VAR is unset"
fi
if [ -z "${VAR-unset}" ]; then
    echo "VAR is set to the empty string"
fi
if [ -n "${VAR}" ]; then
    echo "VAR is set to a non-empty string"
fi
if [ -n "${VAR+set}" ]; then
    echo "VAR is set, possibly to the empty string"
fi
if [ -n "${VAR-unset}" ]; then
    echo "VAR is either unset or set to a non-empty string"
fi
```

Here is the same thing but in handy table form:

```
                        +-------+-------+-----------+
                VAR is: | unset | empty | non-empty |
+-----------------------+-------+-------+-----------+
| [ -z "${VAR}" ]       | true  | true  | false     |
| [ -z "${VAR+set}" ]   | true  | false | false     |
| [ -z "${VAR-unset}" ] | false | true  | false     |
| [ -n "${VAR}" ]       | false | false | true      |
| [ -n "${VAR+set}" ]   | false | true  | true      |
| [ -n "${VAR-unset}" ] | true  | false | true      |
+-----------------------+-------+-------+-----------+
```

The `${VAR+foo}` construct expands to the empty string if `VAR` is unset or to `foo` if `VAR` is set to anything (including the empty string).

The `${VAR-foo}` construct expands to the value of `VAR` if set (including set to the empty string) and `foo` if unset.  This is useful for providing user-overridable defaults (e.g., `${COLOR-red}` says to use `red` unless the variable `COLOR` has been set to something).

The reason, why `[ x"${VAR}" = x ]` is often recommended for testing whether a variable is either unset or set to the empty string, is some implementations of the `[` command (also known as `test`) are buggy.  If `VAR` is set to something like `-n`, then some implementations will do the wrong thing when given `[ "${VAR}" = "" ]`, since the first argument to `[` is erroneously interpreted as the `-n` operator, not a string.

Comment: Testing for a variable set to the empty string can also be done using `[ -z "${VAR-set}" ]`.

Comment: @nwellnhof:  Thanks!  I updated my answer to use the briefer syntax.

Comment: In bash, there's also a difference between `${VAR+foo}` and `${VAR:+foo}`. The former would evaluate to `foo` only if `VAR` is unset, and the version with `:` will also return `foo` if `VAR` is set to the empty string.

Comment: The unset checks aren't reliable. If the user called `set -u` or `set -o nounset` in bash, then the test will just result in the error "bash: VAR: unbound variable". See https://stackoverflow.com/a/13864829 for a more reliable unset check. My go-to check for whether a variable is null or unset is `[ -z "${VAR:-}" ]`. My check for whether a variable is non-empty is `[ "${VAR:-}" ]`.

Answer (score 47):

`-z` is a the best way.

Another options I've used is to set a variable, but it can be overridden by another variable eg

```
export PORT=${MY_PORT:-5432}
```

If the `$MY_PORT` variable is empty, then `PORT` gets set to 5432, otherwise PORT is set to the value of `MY_PORT`. Note the syntax include the colon and dash.

Comment: Accidentally found this today, and it was exactly what I wanted.  Thanks!  I have to tolerate `set -o nounset` in some scripts.

Answer (score 25):

If you're interested in distinguishing the cases of set-empty versus unset status, look at the -u option for bash:

```
$ set -u
$ echo $BAR
bash: BAR: unbound variable
$ [ -z "$BAR" ] && echo true
bash: BAR: unbound variable
$ BAR=""
$ echo $BAR

$ [ -z "$BAR" ] && echo true
true
```

Answer (score 11):

An alternate I've seen to `[ -z "$foo" ]` is the following, however I'm not sure why people use this method, anyone know?

```
[ "x${foo}" = "x" ]
```

Anyway if you're disallowing unset variables (either by `set -u` or `set -o nounset`), then you'll run into trouble with both of those methods. There's a simple fix to this:

```
[ -z "${foo:-}" ]
```

Note: this will leave your variable undef.

Comment: There's a comment about the alternative to `-z` at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/test.html. Basically, it isn't meant to be an alternative to `-z`. Rather, it handles cases where `$foo` could expand to something beginning with a metacharacter that `[` or `test` would be confused by. Putting an arbitrary non-metacharacter at the beginning eliminates that possibility.

Answer (score 7):

the entire if-then and -z are unnecessary.

```
[ "$foo" ] && echo "foo is not empty"
[ "$foo" ] || echo "foo is indeed empty"
```

Comment: That will fail if foo contains only spaces

Comment: Will also fail in some shells if *foo* begins with a dash since it is interpreted as an option. E.g. on solaris *ksh*, *zsh* and *bash* are no problem, *sh* and */bin/test* will fail

Answer (score 6):

The **question** asks **how to check if a variable is an empty string** and the best answers are already given for that.
But I landed here after a period passed programming in php and what I was actually searching was a check like the *empty function in php* working in a bash shell.
After reading the answers I realized I was not thinking properly in bash, but anyhow in that moment a function like *empty* in php would have been soooo handy in my bash code.
As I think this can happen to others, I decided to convert the php empty function in bash

According to the [php manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php):
**a variable is considered empty if it doesn't exist or if its value is one of the following:**

- "" (an empty string)
- 0 (0 as an integer)
- 0.0 (0 as a float)
- "0" (0 as a string)
- an empty array
- a variable declared, but without a value

Of course the *null* and *false* cases cannot be converted in bash, so they are omitted.

```
function empty
{
    local var="$1"

    # Return true if:
    # 1.    var is a null string ("" as empty string)
    # 2.    a non set variable is passed
    # 3.    a declared variable or array but without a value is passed
    # 4.    an empty array is passed
    if test -z "$var"
    then
        [[ $( echo "1" ) ]]
        return

    # Return true if var is zero (0 as an integer or "0" as a string)
    elif [ "$var" == 0 2> /dev/null ]
    then
        [[ $( echo "1" ) ]]
        return

    # Return true if var is 0.0 (0 as a float)
    elif [ "$var" == 0.0 2> /dev/null ]
    then
        [[ $( echo "1" ) ]]
        return
    fi

    [[ $( echo "" ) ]]
}
```

Example of usage:

```
if empty "${var}"
    then
        echo "empty"
    else
        echo "not empty"
fi
```

Demo:
the following snippet:

```
#!/bin/bash

vars=(
    ""
    0
    0.0
    "0"
    1
    "string"
    " "
)

for (( i=0; i<${#vars[@]}; i++ ))
do
    var="${vars[$i]}"

    if empty "${var}"
        then
            what="empty"
        else
            what="not empty"
    fi
    echo "VAR \"$var\" is $what"
done

exit
```

outputs:

```
VAR "" is empty
VAR "0" is empty
VAR "0.0" is empty
VAR "0" is empty
VAR "1" is not empty
VAR "string" is not empty
VAR " " is not empty
```

**Having said that in a bash logic the checks on zero in this function can cause side problems imho, anyone using this function should evaluate this risk and maybe decide to cut those checks off leaving only the first one.**

Comment: Inside the function `empty` - why did you write `[[ $( echo "1" ) ]] ; return` instead of simply `return 1` ?

Answer (score 5):

Personally prefer more clear way to check :

```
if [ "${VARIABLE}" == "" ]; then
  echo VARIABLE is empty
else
  echo VARIABLE is not empty
fi
```

Comment: Some shells do not accept the double equal sign.

Comment: The question was about bash. I'm using bash. Works well for me. What exactly You are speaking about ?

Comment: If you're using Bash, you should use double square brackets. My previous comment was a simple statement of fact for those who might read your answer and be using a different shell.

Comment: single square brackets are ok in this case, please see http://serverfault.com/questions/52034/what-is-the-difference-between-double-and-single-square-brackets-in-bash

Answer (score 5):

My 5 cents: there is also a shorter syntax than `if ...`, this one:

```
VALUE="${1?"Usage: $0 value"}"
```

This line will set VALUE if an argument has been supplied and will print an error message prepended with the script line number in case of an error (and will terminate the script execution).

Another example can be found in the [abs-guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html) (search for «Example 10-7»).

Answer (score 4):

This is true exactly when $FOO is set and empty:

```
[ "${FOO+x}" = x ] && [ -z "$FOO" ]
```

Answer (score 4):

oneliner extension of [duffbeer703](https://serverfault.com/users/2224/duffbeer703)'s solution:

```
#! /bin/bash
[ -z "$1" ] || some_command_that_needs_$1_parameter
```

Answer (score 0):

To figure out if a variable "Foo" is empty and also contains no spaces (or no whitespace as some people refer it).

```
 if [[ -n "${Foo/[ ]*\n/}" ]];then

    echo "Foo is not empty and contains non space characters"

fi


# Another way to solve the same problem: Take spaces out in Foo & check if Foo is empty

 if [[ -z "${Foo// }" ]];then

     echo "Foo is empty"

 fi
```

Answer (score -1):

Not an exact answer, but ran into this trick.  If the string you're looking for comes from "a command" then you can actually store the command in an env. variable and then execute it every time for the if statement, then no brackets required!

For example this command, which determines if you're on debian:

`grep debian /proc/version`

full example:

```
IS_DEBIAN="grep -i debian /proc/version"

if $IS_DEBIAN; then
  echo 'yes debian'
else
  echo 'non debian'
fi
```

So this is like an indirect way (rerunning it every time) to check for an empty string (it happens to be checking for error response from the command, but it also happens to be returning an empty string).

Answer (score -1):

I prefer the way how PHP checks for an empty variable as Luca mentioned in [his answer](https://serverfault.com/a/423408/44086), too. But instead of using a separate function, I use a "filter" which finally allows using usual bash conditions.

Imagine you have a bash script with a settings section like this:

```
# enable test mode
dry_run=false

# overwrite files if they already exist
overwrite_files=true
```

The users of the script should be able to set it as they like:

```
dry_run=
dry_run=""
dry_run=0
dry_run="0"
dry_run=false
dry_run="false"
# or delete it completely
```

So in the script section itself I do this:

```
# check user settings
[[ $dry_run == 0 ]] || [[ $dry_run == false ]] && unset dry_run
[[ $overwrite_files == 0 ]] || [[ $overwrite_files == false ]] && unset overwrite_files
```

Now, I can be sure that the variable exists with a content or not, so I can use a usual condition like this:

```
if [[ $dry_run ]]; then
  echo "dry run is true"
else
  echo "dry run is false"
fi
```

PS I skipped filtering "0.0" as I don't think a user would disable a setting by setting this, but feel free to extend the filter if you need it.