# What is the difference between double and single square brackets in bash?

Tags: bash, scripting, shell, posix

I just wondered what exactly the difference between

```sh
[[ $STRING != foo ]]
```

and

```sh
[ $STRING != foo ]
```

is, apart from that the latter is POSIX-compliant, found in sh and the former is an extension found in bash.

Comment: In case you were also wondering about using no brackets at all, e.g. in the context of an `if` statement, see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#if_.5Bgrep_foo_myfile.5D

Comment: also, From Ubuntu's docs: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh#I_am_a_developer._How_can_I_avoid_this_problem_in_future.3F

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542832/difference-between-single-and-double-square-brackets-in-bash, https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3831/in-bash-are-if-z-1-and-if-1-the-same

Comment: See related on Stack Overflow: [unary operator expected](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13617843/3258851)

Answer (score 389, accepted):

There are several differences.  In my opinion, a few of the most important are:

1. `[` is a builtin in Bash and many other modern shells. The builtin `[` is similar to `test` with the additional requirement of a closing `]`. The builtins `[` and `test` imitate the functionality `/bin/[` and `/bin/test` along with their limitations so that scripts would be backwards compatible. The original executables still exist mostly for POSIX compliance and backwards compatibility. Running the command `type [` in Bash indicates that `[` is interpreted as a builtin by default. (Note: `which [` only looks for executables on the *PATH* and is equivalent to `type -P [`. You can execute `type --help` for details)
2. `[[` is not as compatible, it won't necessarily work with whatever `/bin/sh` points to.  So `[[` is the more modern Bash / Zsh / Ksh option.
3. Because `[[` is built into the shell and does not have legacy requirements, you don't need to worry about word splitting based on the *IFS* variable to mess up on variables that evaluate to a string with spaces.  Therefore, you don't really need to put the variable in double quotes.

For the most part, the rest is just some nicer syntax.  To see more differences, I recommend this link to an FAQ answer: [What is the difference between test, [ and [[ ?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031).  In fact, if you are serious about bash scripting, I recommend reading the entire [wiki](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/), including the FAQ, [Pitfalls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls), and Guide.  [The test section from the guide section](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals#Conditional_Blocks_.28if.2C_test_and_.5B.5B.29) explains these differences as well, and why the author(s) think `[[` is a better choice if you don't need to worry about being as portable.  The main reasons are:

1. You don't have to worry about quoting the left-hand side of the test so that it actually gets read as a variable.
2. You don't have to escape less than and greater than `< >` with backslashes in order for them not to get evaluated as input redirection, which can really mess some stuff up by overwriting files.  This again goes back to `[[` being a builtin. If [ (test) is an external program the shell would have to make an exception in the way it evaluates `<` and `>` only if `/bin/test` is being called, which wouldn't really make sense.

Comment: Thanks, the link to the bash FAQ was what I was looking for (did not know about that page, thanks).

Comment: I edited your post with this information, but [ and test are executed as builtins. The builtins were designed to replace /bin/[ and /bin/test but needed to reproduce the limitations of the binaries too.

The command 'type [' verifies that the builtin is used. 'which [' only searches for executables on the PATH and is equivalent to 'type -P ['

Answer (score 162):

In Short:

> [ is a bash **Builtin**
>
> [[ ]] are bash **Keywords**

**Keywords:** Keywords are quite like builtins, but the main difference is that special parsing rules apply to them. For example, [ is a bash builtin, while [[ is a bash keyword. They are both used for testing stuff, but since [[ is a keyword rather than a builtin, it benefits from a few special parsing rules which make it a lot easier:

```
  $ [ a < b ]
 -bash: b: No such file or directory
  $ [[ a < b ]]
```

The first example returns an error because bash tries to redirect the file b to the command [ a ]. The second example actually does what you expect it to. The character < no longer has its special meaning of File Redirection operator.

Source: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/CommandsAndArguments

Comment: `[` is a POSIX shell command; it need not be built in.  `]` is just an argument which that command looks for, so that the syntax is balanced. The command is a synonym for `test` except that `test` doesn't look for a closing `]`.

Comment: See here: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/test.html

Answer (score 110):

**Behavior differences**

Some differences on Bash 4.3.11:

- POSIX vs Bash extension:

  - `[` [is POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html)
  - `[[` [is a Bash extension](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Conditional-Constructs.html#index-_005b_005b) inspired from Korn shell
- regular command vs magic

  - `[` is just a regular command with a weird name.

    `]` is just the last argument of `[`.

  Ubuntu 16.04 actually has an executable for it at `/usr/bin/[` provided by [coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/test-invocation.html#test-invocation), but the bash built-in version takes precedence.

  Nothing is altered in the way that Bash parses the command.

  In particular, `<` is redirection, `&&` and `||` concatenate multiple commands, `( )` generates subshells unless escaped by `\`, and word expansion happens as usual.

  - `[[ X ]]` is a single construct that makes `X` be parsed magically. `<`, `&&`, `||` and `()` are treated specially, and word splitting rules are different.

    There are also further differences like `=` and `=~`.

  In Bashese: `[` is a built-in command, and `[[` is a keyword: https://askubuntu.com/questions/445749/whats-the-difference-between-shell-builtin-and-shell-keyword
- `<`

  - `[[ a < b ]]`: lexicographical comparison
  - `[ a \< b ]`: Same as above. `\` required or else does redirection like for any other command. Bash extension.
  - `expr x"$x" \< x"$y" > /dev/null` or `[ "$(expr x"$x" \< x"$y")" = 1 ]`: POSIX equivalents, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21294867/how-to-test-strings-for-lexicographic-less-than-or-equal-in-bash/52707989#52707989
- `&&` and `||`

  - `[[ a = a && b = b ]]`: true, logical *and*
  - `[ a = a && b = b ]`: syntax error, `&&` parsed as an AND command separator `cmd1 && cmd2`
  - `[ a = a ] && [ b = b ]`: POSIX reliable equivalent
  - `[ a = a -a b = b ]`: almost equivalent, but deprecated by POSIX because it is insane and fails for some values of `a` or `b` like `!` or `(` which would be interpreted as logical operations
- `(`

  - `[[ (a = a || a = b) && a = b ]]`: false. Without `( )`, would be true because `[[ && ]]` has greater precedence than `[[ || ]]`
  - `[ ( a = a ) ]`: syntax error, `()` is interpreted as a subshell
  - `[ \( a = a -o a = b \) -a a = b ]`: equivalent, but `()`, `-a`, and `-o` are deprecated by POSIX. Without `\( \)` would be true because `-a` has greater precedence than `-o`
  - `{ [ a = a ] || [ a = b ]; } && [ a = b ]` non-deprecated POSIX equivalent. In this particular case however, we could have written just: `[ a = a ] || [ a = b ] && [ a = b ]` because the `||` and `&&` shell operators have equal precedence unlike `[[ || ]]` and `[[ && ]]` and `-o`, `-a` and `[`
- word splitting and filename generation upon expansions (split+glob)

  - `x='a b'; [[ $x = 'a b' ]]`: true, quotes not needed
  - `x='a b'; [ $x = 'a b' ]`: syntax error, expands to `[ a b = 'a b' ]`
  - `x='*'; [ $x = 'a b' ]`: syntax error if there's more than one file in the current directory.
  - `x='a b'; [ "$x" = 'a b' ]`: POSIX equivalent
- `=`

  - `[[ ab = a? ]]`: true, because it does [pattern matching](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_13) (`* ? [` are magic). Does not glob expand to files in current directory.
  - `[ ab = a? ]`: `a?` glob expands. So may be true or false depending on the files in the current directory.
  - `[ ab = a\? ]`: false, not glob expansion
  - `=` and `==` are the same in both `[` and `[[`, but `==` is a Bash extension.
  - `case ab in (a?) echo match; esac`: POSIX equivalent
  - `[[ ab =~ 'ab?' ]]`: false, loses magic with `''` in Bash 3.2 and above and provided compatibility to bash 3.1 is not enabled (like with `BASH_COMPAT=3.1`)
  - `[[ ab? =~ 'ab?' ]]`: true
- `=~`

  - `[[ ab =~ ab? ]]`: true, POSIX [extended regular expression](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04) match, `?` does not glob expand
  - `[ a =~ a ]`: syntax error. No bash equivalent.
  - `printf 'ab\n' | grep -Eq 'ab?'`: POSIX equivalent (single line data only)
  - `awk 'BEGIN{exit !(ARGV[1] ~ ARGV[2])}' ab 'ab?'`: POSIX equivalent.

**Recommendation: always use `[]`**

There are POSIX equivalents for every `[[ ]]` construct I've seen.

If you use `[[ ]]` you:

- lose portability
- force the reader to learn the intricacies of another bash extension. `[` is just a regular command with a weird name, no special semantics are involved.

Thanks to [Stéphane Chazelas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22565/st%C3%A9phane-chazelas) for important corrections and additions.

Comment: How to use `printf 'ab' | grep -Eq 'ab?'` within `if [ … ]`?

Comment: @meeDamian `if ( printf 'ab' | grep -Eq 'a' ); then echo 'a'; fi`. `[]` is a command just like `grep`. The `()` may not be needed on that command I'm not sure: I added it because of the `|`, depends on how Bash parses things. If there was no `|` I'm sure you can write just `if cmd arg arg; then`.

Comment: @meeDamian yeah, no need for `()` it seems: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8965509/why-if-ps-aux-grep-always-succeeds-in-bash

Comment: Nice list! See also:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh#I_am_a_developer._How_can_I_avoid_this_problem_in_future.3F

Comment: Contrary to this answer, Google's Shell Style Guide recommends using `[[ ]]` in bash scripts: "`[[ … ]]` is preferred over `[ … ]`, `test` and `/usr/bin/[`." See [link](https://google.github.io/styleguide/shellguide.html#s6.3-tests).

Answer (score 21):

**Single Bracket** i.e. `[]` is POSIX shell compliant to to enclose a conditional expression.

**Double Brackets** i.e. `[[]]` is an enhanced (or extension) version of  standard POSIX version, this is supported by bash and other shells(zsh,ksh).

In bash, for numeric comparison we use `eq`, `ne`,`lt` and `gt`, with double brackets for comparison we can use `==`, `!=`, `<,` and `>` literally.

- `[` is a synonym for test command. Even if it is built in to the shell it creates a new process.
- `[[` is a new improved version of it, which is a keyword, not a program.

for example:

```
[ var1 lt var2] #works
[ var1 < var2] #error: var2 No such file or directory 
[ var1 \< var2] #works with escape
[[ var1 < var2]] #works
```

Answer (score 10):

Based on a quick reading of the relevant sections of the manpage, the primary difference appears to be that the `==` and `!=` operators match against a pattern, rather than a literal string, and also that there's the `=~` regex comparison operator.