# How can I find out which version of shell (bash and/or ksh) start to support ==

Tags: bash

both  [[ string1 == string2 ]] and [[ string1 = string2 ]] means equal. But some other guy told me their machine don't support ==. The error message is: syntax error: `==' unexpected.

Seems they use pretty old UNIX with korn shell and I'm using REHL5.2. Since I cannot access their machines, how do I find out which version start to support "=="?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can look at the value of `$SHELL` and see if it's set to the shell's executable. You could then test and branch on the value of it, or lack thereof; I don't know if this will be set on older shells.

If you don't need the advanced features of `[[` then use `[` instead. [This web page explains the differences in detail.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031) Also take a look at [this related question](https://serverfault.com/q/52034/68739).

If you are only going to compare strings with `==` then use the POSIX syntax for the greatest compatibility: `[ string1 = string2 ]` which uses a single equals sign.

Answer (score 0):

If the user is in fact using a KSH/Korn shell, the problem may not be the `==`, but instead the lack of double quotes, as many of the AT&T standards now take the `==` per the `--posix` or `-o posix` flags set. *(These two flags force KSH to utilize posix standards)*

Long story short, you should use:
`if [ "$instance" = "ALL" ]; then`

The double quotes protect against cases of `null` or otherwise `empty` strings, which would most likely throw an error, even if syntax was correct.

**Bonus:** It's not that KSH lacks support for `==` it's that KSH lacks support for `null` and `empty` objects/returns.

For more information on this, you can check out [the main KSH page](http://www.kornshell.com/), or Peter Seebach's book on [Portable Shell Scripting](https://amzn.to/2WKGoTN) or even the [O'Reilly Bash Cookbook](https://amzn.to/2LlOhd3), and finally the [Korn Shell book by O'Reilly](https://amzn.to/3biy3Mv) which I happened to find a freely accessible short link of some of these logical operands [here](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix3/korn/appb_05.htm) :)